# JQuery switch based on window.location.pathname with regex

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a switch statement based on `window.location.pathname` but one of the cases that I'm trying to account for will have a number at the end, anything from 1 to X. What's the best method of tackling this? I've looked into a regex approach but can't seem to get it right.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    switch (window.location.pathname) {
        case '/dashboard':
            $('.dashboard').addClass('active');
            break;
        case '/dashboard/inquiries':
            $('.inquiries').addClass('active');
            break;
        case '/dashboard/cms':
        case '/dashboard/cms/edit-header':
        case '/dashboard/cms/grid/1234': << this is the part in question.
            $('.cms').addClass('active');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't. Switch requires fixed values. With a regular expression you'll obtain true or false, that's not a valid value for your switch. Maybe you can switch module (inquiries and cms), and then call to a function that split the url (`array[cms => [edit-header, grid]]`) and evaluate separately.

Comment: @billyonecan Perfect! so simple & worked like a charm, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove any digits from the end of the path before your switch:

```
var x = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/\d+$/, '');

switch (x) {
    ...
    case '/dashboard/cms/grid':
        $('.cms').addClass('active');
        break;
    ...
}
```